# asp.net core rewrite middleware not rewriting, possible regex issue

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, asp.net-core, middleware

(I am using VS2017 and asp.net core v1.1.1)
Hi,

I am trying to make my url's more seo friendly, I have added the .net core rewriting middleware via nuget, and followed this guide https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/url-rewriting

For some reason my URL's are not being re-written.
My URL's are currently /Albums?slug=first-test and I want them to be Albums/first-test

This is what I have come up with (from startup.cs) :

```
 var options = new RewriteOptions()
.AddRewrite(@"^(.*)?slug=(.*)", "$1/$2", skipRemainingRules: true)
.AddRewrite(@"^Albums?slug=(.*)", "Albums/$1", skipRemainingRules: true);
 app.UseRewriter(options);
```

As you can see I am attempting 2 varations that I hope to have the same outcome, this is because I also have /Galleries?slug=first-test and I was hoping that I could get away with one rule for both.

Answer (score 0):

So, it seems I made a noob mistake.  All I needed to do was map new routes!
I noticed how Controller/Action/id didn't contain ?id= which reminded me of my earlier days of learning, in fact day one of it lol.  So here's what I added:

```
    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{slug?}");

    });
```

Edit:
Changed the optional in the end as adding new routes broke my home index.